# How do I go about creating an always capitalized input in vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm creating a form using vue.js and I need to create inputs in vue that is always capitalized. I know I could use the css property

`text-transform: uppercase;`

and then transform the data before sending using

`data.someData.toUpperCase()`

But I wonder if there is a more intelligent way of doing that in vue.js. In react we can create controlled inputs and easily do it. Is there anything like that in Vue.js?

I managed to do it using computed fields, however, I would have to create computed getter and setter for each input in the form. Is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: You should take a look at `computed` properties. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html

Comment: However I have to create a computed getter and setter for every field. I thought there was a way of doing that just once for every input.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a custom directive.

```
Vue.directive( 'touppercase', {
    update (el) {
        el.value = el.value.toUpperCase()
    },
})
```

And then use it where you need. For example:

```
<input type="text" v-model="modelfield" v-touppercase>
```

Comment: It does work, however it sends the word with the last letter in lower case to the server...

Comment: it does not work, because the last character is lower case.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't have a lot of code to run, you should manually bind events to your textfield and then handle the uppercasing there.

Handling events from a text field can be done by adding an `input` event handler on them, and then updating the initial state again.

```
<input :value="text" @input="updateText($event.target.value)"/>

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            text: '',
        }
    },
    methods: {
        updateText(newValue) {
            this.value = newValue.toUpperCase();
        },
    }
}
```

You can also do it inline in a template, but this might make it harder to read depending on your code style preferences

```
<input :value="text" @input="text = $event.target.value.toUpperCase()"/>
```

Comment: I would still have to created a method for every single field on form.

Comment: @IanPierreGomes I added a variant that shows the the code on a single line

Answer (score 1):

This directive works fine with `v-model` (last character is in upper case too):

```
Vue.directive('uppercase', {
  update(el) {
    const sourceValue = el.value;
    const newValue = sourceValue.toUpperCase();

    if (sourceValue !== newValue) {
      el.value = newValue;
      el.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true }));
    }
  },
});
```

Usage:

```
<input type="text" v-model="myField" v-uppercase />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
<input :value="theValue" @input="theValue = theValue.toUpperCase()"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

as a fix for asologor's answer you should reach input element to change it at vuetify

```
Vue.directive("uppercase", {
    update(el) {
        const sourceValue = el.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value
        const newValue = sourceValue.toUpperCase()

        if (sourceValue !== newValue) {
            el.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value = newValue
            el = el.getElementsByTagName("input")[0]
            el.dispatchEvent(new Event("input", { bubbles: true }))
        }
    }
})
```

and usage is

```
 <v-text-field
              type="text"
              outlined
              placeholder="placeholder"
              v-model="name"
              prepend-inner-icon="edit"
              v-uppercase
            />
```

this is defnetely working